# How to use tts service in a kde plasma menu?

Tags: javascript, qml, text-to-speech

I forked EQMenu fork, I changed the appearence, but now i would like use tts software to tell the name of item, so I write this, but where is the mistake ?
I try to find a method to do it, now i try this :

in the menu the logic was create by :
tools.js

```
function tospeak(TextToSpeech) {
    var process = require('child_process');
    process.exec('/etc/alternatives/tts'+TextToSpeech,function (err,stdout,stderr) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("\n"+stderr);
        } else {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    });
}
```

/etc/alternatives/tts its to choose with different tts software.

In this file it is the QML code of menu:

ItemGridDelegate.qml

```
-
import "../code/tools.js" as Tools
-
-
    PlasmaCore.IconItem {
        id: icon

        y: showLabel ? (2 * highlightItemSvg.margins.top) : 0

        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: showLabel ? undefined : parent.verticalCenter

        width: mouseArea.containsMouse ? iconSize*1.25 : iconSize
        height: width

        animated: false
        usesPlasmaTheme: item.GridView.view.usesPlasmaTheme

        source: model.decoration
    }

    PlasmaComponents.Label {
        id: label

        visible: showLabel

        anchors {
            top: icon.bottom
            topMargin: units.smallSpacing
            left: parent.left
            leftMargin: highlightItemSvg.margins.left
            right: parent.right
            rightMargin: highlightItemSvg.margins.right
        }

        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

        elide: Text.ElideRight
        wrapMode: Text.NoWrap

        font.pointSize: mouseArea.containsMouse ? 26 : 14

        text: model.display

        Tools.tospeak(model.display.toString());

    }
    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
    }
```

ItemGridView.qml

```
-
import "../code/tools.js" as Tools
-
-
        id: dropArea

        anchors.fill: parent

        onDragMove: {
            if (!dragEnabled || gridView.animating) {
                return;
            }

            var cPos = mapToItem(gridView.contentItem, event.x, event.y);
            var item = gridView.itemAt(cPos.x, cPos.y);

            if (item && item != kicker.dragSource && kicker.dragSource && kicker.dragSource.parent == gridView.contentItem) {
                item.GridView.view.model.moveRow(dragSource.itemIndex, item.itemIndex);
            }
            Tools.tospeak(item.itemIndex.toString())
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with an extension of QML, its module is write in Qt/C++.

To see all Code go to here https://github.com/handyopensource/dvkbuntu-vocalfly